# MySQL INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and IGNORE

Tags: mysql

I'm entering a lot of data to MySQL which frequently is updated, (based on unique index).

Given the following statement...

```
INSERT INTO 'players' ('id', 'parent', 'child_name')
VALUES
('1', '100', 'john'),
('2', '200', 'bob'),
('3', '300', 'chris')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `parent` = VALUES(`parent`), `child_name` = 
VALUES(`child_name`), `id` = VALUES(`id`)
```

In some scenarios, the feed is incorrect and the parent does not exist so it fails with a error of..

`Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

What I would like to know is, does it insert the good rows on this `bulk` upsert or does the whole statement fail, if so do i need add `ignore` to ensure it works?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

MySql with innodb (likely your engine) is ACID.  All insert statements by default on Innodb are done atomically, meaning if any part of the statement fails, no inserts take place.

You can use IGNORE and any failing value set will be quitely skipped, however I don't recommend this as it will silently hide any other errors (others you might not be expecting).  Why not validate the records meet the constraint before inserting?

Similarly, you could change the transaction setting for and insert tansaction: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html. However, to be honest, I've never done this so I'm unsure how it will turn out if several rows fail.  Will the remaining ones after the failing one stop getting inserted?

Comment: Hi Ray, the amount of data make it difficult to validate it, do you know if ignore can be used in conjuction with on duplicate key insert?

Comment: Yes. Ignore works fine, it just suppresses the error (any error).

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Any way to fetch these errors? Im insert a few thousand records every 10s, so they causing me more hassle than good. But anyway to find them backward?

Comment: Nope, not as far as I know.  Might be worth figuring out how/why are you inserting values that break foreign keys that frequently.

Comment: Ignore reduces errors to warnings, so you still can get information on what failed.